# Zen theme - recommended way to display 2 blocks next to each other in a region

Tags: theming

I'm using a zen subtheme and I want to display 2 blocks next to each other.

[image: Example]

I don't want to create 2 more regions in the info file because it will only be displayed on the home page. (Maybe even 3 blocks on another page)

Trying to move away from panels due to added markup and extra loading times during dev.

Would the correct way be to.

- Add blocks to content region
- Add css aka (width:50%) on the blocks to get the desired layout

or
Is there another theme layer of some-kind I can use for layouts inside of zen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Plain old CSS

Plain old css will work. Set your widths with those two blocks and float them.

### Zen Grids

If you create custom classes the zen grid sass extension can be used as well to set up layouts using sass

More on zen grids:

- http://zengrids.com/help/
- http://thinkshout.com/blog/2013/10/candice/getting-started-sass-drupal-and-zen

### Block class

[Block Class](https://drupal.org/project/block_class) is a good way of setting blocks up to line up accordingly next to each other:

> Block Class allows users to add classes to any block through the block's configuration interface. By adding a very short snippet of PHP to a theme's block.tpl.php file, classes can be added to the parent  element of a block. Hooray for more powerful block theming!

Answer (score 1):

You can put both block in same region by setting it to show on front only, as per your requirement. Give 50-50 space to both of them by CSS.

If you need any more class/id to set their display right, you can use a module [BLOCK CLASS](https://drupal.org/project/block_class) to set unique ID/class for these or any particular block. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Can Zen Grids sass-extension also work for this situation?

Comment: I have never worked on Zen, but it should as what I have proposed is Drupal way to handle this..